# For While Do Loop bash

Tags: bash, loops

I've got the following loop that will print out Url.com/1.jpg to xx.jpg (for any number of my choosing in {1..2})

I need to run this loop for multiple URL's and not interested in adding a new for loop for each URL.

```
for i in {1..2}; do 
echo "'http://url.com/$i.jpg',"
echo "'http://url1.com/$i.jpg'"
done
```

When run as is, I get

```
'http://url.com/1.jpg',
'http://url1.com/1.jpg'
'http://url.com/2.jpg',
'http://url1.com/2.jpg'
```

What is the easiest way to make the text display as:

```
'http://url.com/1.jpg',
'http://url.com/2.jpg',
'http://url1.com/1.jpg'
'http://url1.com/2.jpg'
```

For, While Do?
Nested loops?

Comment: Could just pipe your output into `sort` Assuming this file is named `urls.sh`: `./urls.sh | sort` gives the desired output in this case.

Comment: Why don't you just repeat the `for` with different url?

Comment: if I need to run this against 40 or 50 url's, it gets time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No (explicit) loops! :)

```
printf "'http://url.com/%d.jpg',\n" {1..2}
printf "'http://url1.com/%d.jpg'\n" {1..2}
```

Or, further generalize by adding one loop:

```
urls=(
    "'http://url.com/%d.jpg',"
    "'http://url1.com/%d.jpg'"
)
for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
    printf "$url\n" {1..2}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use two for loops.

```
for i in {1..2}; do 
echo "'http://url.com/$i.jpg',"
done
for i in {1..2}; do 
echo "'http://url1.com/$i.jpg'"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `done` with `done | sort` at the end of your loop.  Or stick your URLs in a second list, as in this example, since lists are typically expanded left to right:

```
$ echo {a,b}{1..3}
a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3
```

The second approach has the benefit of letting you do your wget or whatever in one command, like `wget http://{base_url1,base_url2}/image{1..3}.jpg`, and is a general structure I use at least weekly.

Comment: If you really need them one per line, you could also use `printf '%s\n'` instead of `echo`.